Complex polynomial of degree n
I have the following problem:
Assume f is entire and lim$_{z→∞}|f(z)|=∞$, define $g(z)$ as $
g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{\prod_{a \in Z} (z - a)},
$ where $Z$ is the set of all zeros of $f(z)$. Then $g(z)$ is entire and never zero. Prove that $g(z)$ is constant, and hence $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$. $\textbf{Hint:}$ Define $h(z) = \frac{1}{g(z)}$, and show that $|h(z)| \leq A|z|^n$ for $|z|$ large enough. Conclude that $h(z)$ is a polynomial of degree at most $n$ using the extended Liouville's theorem.
I have some doubts as to how each part implies the other. How does $g(z)$ being constant imply that $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$? How does showing $h(z)$ being a polynomial imply the it $f(z)$ is also? I am having a lot of problems with these polynomial types questions, I cannot really wrap my head a around it. The more in-depth the answer, the best, even though it maybe only for one of the questions. Nevertheless, any feedback is appreciated! Also, any link to resources explaining complex polynomials intuitively would be nice, or any tips and tricks in how to deal with them are greatly helpful.

At least your first question: How does $g(z)$ being... has an immediate answer if you look at the definition of $g$...

@mathcounterexamples.net It's not that immediate, because you also need to show that $Z$ is finite. (this follows quiet easily from properties of holomorphic functions, but this still has to be done)

As $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} \lvert f(z) \rvert = \infty$, it exists $R \gt 0$ such $\lvert f(z) \rvert \ge 1$ outside the closed disk $D_R$ centered at the origin and with radius equal to $R$.
Therefore, the set $Z$ of zeros of $f$ counted with their multiplicity is included in $D_R$. As those roots are isolated and $D_R$ is compact, $Z$ is finite and $g$ well defined. Denote $\overline{f}(z) = \prod_{a \in Z} (z - a)$ and $n$ the cardinal of $Z$.
As $\lim\limits_{z \to \infty} \lvert 1/f(z) \rvert = 0$, $\lvert h(z) \rvert \le A \lvert z \rvert^n$ for $\lvert z \rvert$ large enough. According to Liouville's theorem, $h$ is a polynomial $p$ of degree at most $n$. We have
$$g(z) = \frac{f(z)}{\overline{f}(z)} = \frac{1}{p(z)}.$$
As $g$ has no poles, $p$ is constant and therefore $g$ too. Finally, $f = K \overline{f}$ is a polynomial.
